# importing text into Excel - with multiple lines per cell?

Tags: excel, csv, import

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
product number: 12345
product info:
...lots of random text here...
...spread over many lines...
```

this format repeats for 100s of products.

I've tried importing this into Excel using the text wizard, but without much luck so far. I want the Excel import to look this this:

```
Col A    Col B
12345    ...all the product info text in one cell...
```

..and repeat for each entry in the list.

Using the text wizard, I can only import and split to different columns. It doesn't get me close to what I'm trying to do. Is there some trick or another tool I can use for this?

Thanks.

update: an example> http://pastebin.com/DR50aHnL  (just to clarify - this format repeats over and over for 100s for products)

Comment: Is it one product per file?

Comment: I don't think the Excel importer will do the trick here.

Comment: The file has many products, repeating over and over using the symatics I put above

Comment: Can you put a sample?

Comment: here's an example: http://pastebin.com/DR50aHnL which repeats for 100s of products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this problem by manually making this text file a CSV, by using sublime text to insert the required commas & quotes. Then everything worked as expected!